# Error when constructing a stateful RNN in Keras using TimeDistributed layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, stateful

I currently try to re-create a model from a paper (similar to https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.00894.pdf, page 5) in Keras with TensorFlow backend, but seem to get stuck when constructing a stateful RNN that has a `TimeDistributed` layer in the beginning.

Here is my stripped-down code for the problematic part:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(
    Conv2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        padding="same",
        data_format="channels_last"
    ),
    name="C1",
    batch_input_shape=(1, None, 80, 128, 3)
))

# (leaving out the pooling)

model.add(ConvLSTM2D(
    filters=10,
    kernel_size=(3,3),
    padding="same",
    return_sequences=True,
    stateful=True
))
```

When the `stateful` parameter in the ConvLSTM2D layer is set to `true`, I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size. Specify the batch size of your input tensors: 
- If using a Sequential model, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_input_shape` argument to your first layer.
- If using the functional API, specify the time dimension by passing a `batch_shape` argument to your Input layer.
The same thing goes for the number of rows and columns.
```

I've also tried adding the following Input layer, but that does not seem to help:

```py
model.add(Input(
    name="input",
    batch_input_shape=(1, None, 80, 128, 3)
))
```

Also, I've constructed the same model with the the functional API (using `batch_shape` instead of `batch_input_shape`), but there I get the same error message.

I've read some threads about this topic, but none of the solutions seemed to do the trick for me. Maybe I just overlook some obvious mistake...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to move the `batch_input_shape` in the inside of the Conv layer & add the `input_shape` with build command.

```
model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
    keras.layers.Conv2D(
        filters=40,
        kernel_size=(3,3),
        padding="same",
        data_format="channels_last",
        batch_input_shape=(1, None, 80, 128, 3)
    ),
    name="C1",
))
#.. After other commands
model.build(input_shape=(1,1,80,128,3))
```

Note that I am not sure about the correctness of the input shapes. I just put shapes that helped to construct the network and not raise the error you faced. This code gives the resulting network

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
C1 (TimeDistributed)         multiple                  1120
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d (ConvLSTM2D)    multiple                  18040
=================================================================
Total params: 19,160
Trainable params: 19,160
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thank you, that kind of does it, but not fully. When the input shape in build() is (1,1,80,128,3), it compiles, but not with an input shape of (1,None,80,128). Then there is the same error message. Is there some way to fix that?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. I have tried to construct the model using `(1,None,80,128,3)` input shape, but couldn't resolve the error. Good luck with finding the answer.